# Run a single java package on eclipse using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have multiple java packages in my java project. Is it possible to run a single package on eclipse using maven. I want to do it with the project level pom. I dont want to create POMs for every package.

Comment: could you elaborate it more what you mean by multiple package s (are you referring to Java package or packagable apps ?)

Comment: java packages. I have few selenium test cases that I fixed in a particular package and I want to confirm it works fine.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is only one POM per project, not per package.

Comment: As @Tunaki said, There could be only one pom for Java project, you don't need pom.xml per Java package

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, not sure if this is what you are looking for but I use a configuration variable to run test cases for a particular package. You have to add a plugin to the POM to achieve this.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/${testGroup}/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now if you want to run the test cases for lets say package org/myPackage you would use a command like this.

```
mvn test -DtestGroup=org/myPackage
```